# Python: cannot convert float NaN to integer

Tags: python, machine-learning, time-series

I am trying to run this code:

def train_dqn(env):

```
class Q_Network(chainer.Chain):

    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, output_size):
        super(Q_Network, self).__init__(
            fc1 = L.Linear(input_size, hidden_size),
            fc2 = L.Linear(hidden_size, hidden_size),
            fc3 = L.Linear(hidden_size, output_size)
        )

    def __call__(self, x):
        h = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        h = F.relu(self.fc2(h))
        y = self.fc3(h)
        return y

    def reset(self):
        self.zerograds()

Q = Q_Network(input_size=env.history_t+1, hidden_size=100, output_size=3)
Q_ast = copy.deepcopy(Q)
optimizer = chainer.optimizers.Adam()
optimizer.setup(Q)

epoch_num = 50
step_max = len(env.data)-1
memory_size = 200
batch_size = 20
epsilon = 1.0
epsilon_decrease = 1e-3
epsilon_min = 0.1
start_reduce_epsilon = 200
train_freq = 10
update_q_freq = 20
gamma = 0.97
show_log_freq = 5

memory = []
total_step = 0
total_rewards = []
total_losses = []

start = time.time()
for epoch in range(epoch_num):

    pobs = env.reset()
    step = 0
    done = False
    total_reward = 0
    total_loss = 0

    while not done and step < step_max:

        # select act
        pact = np.random.randint(3)
        if np.random.rand() > epsilon:
            pact = Q(np.array(pobs, dtype=np.float32).reshape(1, -1))
            pact = np.argmax(pact.data)

        # act
        obs, reward, done = env.step(pact)

        # add memory
        memory.append((pobs, pact, reward, obs, done))
        if len(memory) > memory_size:
            memory.pop(0)

        # train or update q
        if len(memory) == memory_size:
            if total_step % train_freq == 0:
                shuffled_memory = np.random.permutation(memory)
                memory_idx = range(len(shuffled_memory))
                for i in memory_idx[::batch_size]:
                    batch = np.array(shuffled_memory[i:i+batch_size])
                    b_pobs = np.array(batch[:, 0].tolist(), dtype=np.float32).reshape(batch_size, -1)
                    b_pact = np.array(batch[:, 1].tolist(), dtype=np.int32)
                    b_reward = np.array(batch[:, 2].tolist(), dtype=np.int32)
                    b_obs = np.array(batch[:, 3].tolist(), dtype=np.float32).reshape(batch_size, -1)
                    b_done = np.array(batch[:, 4].tolist(), dtype=np.bool)

                    q = Q(b_pobs)
                    maxq = np.max(Q_ast(b_obs).data, axis=1)
                    target = copy.deepcopy(q.data)
                    for j in range(batch_size):
                        target[j, b_pact[j]] = b_reward[j]+gamma*maxq[j]*(not b_done[j])
                    Q.reset()
                    loss = F.mean_squared_error(q, target)
                    total_loss += loss.data
                    loss.backward()
                    optimizer.update()

            if total_step % update_q_freq == 0:
                Q_ast = copy.deepcopy(Q)

        # epsilon
        if epsilon > epsilon_min and total_step > start_reduce_epsilon:
            epsilon -= epsilon_decrease

        # next step
        total_reward += reward
        pobs = obs
        step += 1
        total_step += 1

    total_rewards.append(total_reward)
    total_losses.append(total_loss)

    if (epoch+1) % show_log_freq == 0:
        log_reward = sum(total_rewards[((epoch+1)-show_log_freq):])/show_log_freq
        log_loss = sum(total_losses[((epoch+1)-show_log_freq):])/show_log_freq
        elapsed_time = time.time()-start
        print('\t'.join(map(str, [epoch+1, epsilon, total_step, log_reward, log_loss, elapsed_time])))
        start = time.time()
                    
return Q, total_losses, total_rewards
```

And when i try to run, this results in "*ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer*":

Q, total_losses, total_rewards = train_dqn(Environment1(train))

i tried this code to resolve this.. but this not helping in this

int(numpy.nan)

Please suggest if anyother code work with this.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In your own words, **what do you think should be the result** if you have `numpy.nan`, and you try to convert it to an integer? Why? Do you understand **why and where the code needs** an integer (that the error message is complaining about)? Do you understand **which value** is `numpy.nan`, and **how** that happened? Do you understand **what part of the code** has the problem, according to the error message? Where exactly are you stuck in attempting to [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) the problem?

Comment: "I am trying to run this code" - is this code that you are trying to write? Or is it code that someone else gave to you? We do not do tech support; we can explain a problem with code that you are trying to write yourself, after you have found a bug and created a [mre], but we cannot help you with using someone else's program - that is off topic here.

Answer (score 0):

This might fix this issue.

For identifying `NaN` values use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
print(df[df['x'].isnull()])
```

Then for removing all non-numeric values use [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) with parameter `errors='coerce'` - to replace non-numeric values to `NaN`s:

```
df['x'] = pd.to_numeric(df['x'], errors='coerce')
```

And for remove all rows with `NaN`s in column `x` use [`dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html):

```
df = df.dropna(subset=['x'])
```

Last convert values to `int`s:

```
df['x'] = df['x'].astype(int)
```